# Scala metals: "Expression type:" appears under the modeline instead of type information

Tags: lsp

I've installed metals according to the instructions here https://scalameta.org/metals/docs/editors/emacs/ and it mostly works (go-to-definition, etc) but there are unfortunate times when instead of type information I just see `Expression type:` under the modeline instead of anything useful. I can use go to definition and then the type for the function I was wondering about appears fine under the modeline but when jumping back, I see `Expression type:` in place of the type I saw before.

Does anyone know why that happens and why showing the type information under modeline seems unstable?

Comment: By "under the modeline" do you mean in the minibuffer, as a prompt? (Or in the echo area, as a message?)

Comment: I don't recall exactly what it's called but it's the area where the results of sexp execution goes or if I try to move my cursor too high/low within the buffer I see `Beginning of buffer` or `End of buffer`, likely the echo area as a message

Comment: That's the *echo area*. See the Emacs [Glossary](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Glossary.html) and manual node [The Echo Area](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Echo-Area.html).